# Trying to align basic form elements in vain

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a basic stylesheet to base forms off of, where standard elements have regular heights in keeping with the line-height.
So far, this is proving something of a painful exercise.

For instance, whilst the text in my input and button elements aligns easily, their bounding boxes are very strange.

As a contrived example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

div {
  height: 24px;
  background: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input,
button,
span {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.large,
.large input,
.large button,
.large span {
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="small">
text<input value="my test"><button>my test</button><span>me</span>text<br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="large">
text<input value="my test"><button>my test</button><span>me</span>text<br>
</div>
```

As you can see, the bounding box for some of the elements (I'm using chrome, latest version) seem quite strange and inconsistent.
I would like to fix those issues, and more importantly, understand them.

Specifically, the first inputs bounding box is erroneously shifted 1 pixel down and the last span has been shifted many pixels down.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: to me, it seems a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve, could you clarify the goal you are trying to achieve a bit more?, like what is it suppost to do, how should it look.

Comment: In theory, the input, button and span items should all have the same height and all their bounding boxes should be aligned vertically. Instead, the vertical position of the bounding box is often shifted vertically or the height isn't quite right.

As specific examples, the first inputs bounding box is erroneously shifted 1 pixel down and the last spans bounding box is shifted many pixels down.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by using `display: flex` for that span and wrap it in a div which will scale to its parent:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

div {
  height: 24px;
  background: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input,
button,
span {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.large {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div.large,
.large input,
.large button {
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="small">
text<input value="my test"><button>my test</button><span>me</span>text<br>
</div>
<br>
<div class="large">
  text<input value="my test"><button>my test</button><div style="border:1px solid;height:100%;display:flex;align-items:center;">me</div>text<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would require changing the structure of the actual html. It works somewhat in the contrived example, but the idea is that users can just use the elements without doing anything fancy.
I also note that the second span has been changed to a div. Not doing so shows how weird the bounding boxes get.

Ideally I would gain some understanding as to what is actually happening and why.